# Exclude only latest post of a category in Wordpress main loop using pre_get_posts?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently excluding all posts from the category 'featured' in my homepage loop using the following function:

```
function main_loop_excludes($query){
  if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()){
    //'featured' cat ID = 531
    $query->set('cat','-531');
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','main_loop_excludes');
```

This works perfectly, but I'd like to only filter out the *most recent post* rather than *all posts* from the 'featured' category. Is this possible?

I've seen ways to filter out specific posts using `WP_Query`, but I'm looking for a way to do it in the main Wordpress loop. `pre_get_posts` feels like the best starting point. Am I on the right track?

---

**EDIT:**

I've used the following code to save the ID of the specific post I want to exclude(saved as variable `$post_to_exclude_ID`):

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
  'category_name' => 'featured',
  'fields'        => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
));
// post ID = 2162
$post_to_exclude_ID = $post_ids[0]; // Save ID of most recent post
```

And now I can use the original `main_loop_excludes` function to filter the main loop to show *only* the post in question, but I can't seem to reverse the process. Adding a minus sign before the ID just breaks the function (the loop then shows *all* posts, ).

New function:

```
function main_loop_excludes($query){
  if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()){
    // Make sure the var is accessible
    global $post_to_exclude_ID;
    // Set the filter
    $query->set('p', $post_to_exclude_ID);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','main_loop_excludes');
```

This does *not* work:

```
$query->set('p', '-2162');
```

But the same style code *does* work for categories:

```
$query->set('cat','-531');
```

NB: thanks to [Valerius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3283331/valerius) for suggesting the idea of finding the post ID and injecting it into the `$query->set...` with a var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest post of a specific category using [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).

With that, we can do the following:

```
function main_loop_excludes($query){
  $latest_featured = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => 1, 'category' => 531));
  if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()){
    //'featured' cat ID = 531
    $query->set('post__not_in',array($latest_featured[0]['ID'])); //exclude queries by post ID
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','main_loop_excludes');
```

Comment: I couldn't get this code to work: kept getting the white screen of death. `wp_get_recent_posts` did lead me to discover the `get_posts` array method I've used to find the needed ID, so thanks for that: main question edited to show where I'm at now. Getting closer, I hope...

Comment: Confusion on my part, sorry. The 'p' argument isn't available. However, post__not_in is (note: double underscore in the name). It takes an array of integers with post IDs to exclude. Updated my code sample above.

Comment: `post__not_in` solved the problem! Not right away, though: the `wp_get_recent_posts(...` part kept giving me the white screen of death. Using the `get_posts` method outlined in the question *did* work, and passing that through `post__not_in` worked perfectly!

Comment: Great! Quick tip: WordPress disables error log output to the screen (hence the "White screen of death"). You can either enable it or output it to a log file via the wp-config.php file, and it'll tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

here is a function that does just that:

```
    function get_lastest_post_of_category($cat){
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'category__in' => (array)$cat);
    $post_is = get_posts( $args );
    return $post_is[0]->ID;
}
```

Usage: say my category id is 22 then:

```
$last_post_ID = get_lastest_post_of_category(22);
```

you can also pass an array of categories to this function.

Comment: How do you get the category ID?

Comment: Hi @Winch 

the category ID in my example is : 22

$last_post_ID = get_lastest_post_of_category(22);